# Convert Open dialog VBA code to 64 bit

Tags: ms-access, vba

A while back I found a piece of code that allows me to call an opendialog to either open or save files. I downloaded Access 2013 and the following code doesn't produce an error. but it doesn't bring up the open dialog.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'***************** Code Start **************
'This code was originally written by Ken Getz.
'It is not to be altered or distributed,
'except as part of an application.
'You are free to use it in any application,
'provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
'
' Code courtesy of:
' Microsoft Access 95 How-To
' Ken Getz and Paul Litwin
' Waite Group Press, 1996
'
'http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm

Type tagOPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    strFilter As String
    strCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    strFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    strFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    strInitialDir As String
    strTitle As String
    Flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    strDefExt As String
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Declare PtrSafe Function aht_apiGetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean

Declare PtrSafe Function aht_apiGetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetSaveFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean
Declare PtrSafe Function CommDlgExtendedError Lib "comdlg32.dll" () As Long

Global Const ahtOFN_READONLY = &H1
Global Const ahtOFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT = &H2
Global Const ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY = &H4
Global Const ahtOFN_NOCHANGEDIR = &H8
Global Const ahtOFN_SHOWHELP = &H10
' You won't use these.
'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLEHOOK = &H20
'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLETEMPLATE = &H40
'Global Const ahtOFN_ENABLETEMPLATEHANDLE = &H80
Global Const ahtOFN_NOVALIDATE = &H100
Global Const ahtOFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT = &H200
Global Const ahtOFN_EXTENSIONDIFFERENT = &H400
Global Const ahtOFN_PATHMUSTEXIST = &H800
Global Const ahtOFN_FILEMUSTEXIST = &H1000
Global Const ahtOFN_CREATEPROMPT = &H2000
Global Const ahtOFN_SHAREAWARE = &H4000
Global Const ahtOFN_NOREADONLYRETURN = &H8000
Global Const ahtOFN_NOTESTFILECREATE = &H10000
Global Const ahtOFN_NONETWORKBUTTON = &H20000
Global Const ahtOFN_NOLONGNAMES = &H40000
' New for Windows 95
Global Const ahtOFN_EXPLORER = &H80000
Global Const ahtOFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS = &H100000
Global Const ahtOFN_LONGNAMES = &H200000

Function TestIt()
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim lngFlags As Long
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Access Files (*.mda, *.mdb)", _
                    "*.MDA;*.MDB")
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "dBASE Files (*.dbf)", "*.DBF")
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Text Files (*.txt)", "*.TXT")
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "All Files (*.*)", "*.*")
    MsgBox "You selected: " & ahtCommonFileOpenSave(InitialDir:="C:\", _
        Filter:=strFilter, FilterIndex:=3, Flags:=lngFlags, _
        DialogTitle:="Hello! Open Me!")
    ' Since you passed in a variable for lngFlags,
    ' the function places the output flags value in the variable.
    Debug.Print Hex(lngFlags)
End Function

Function GetOpenFile(Optional varDirectory As Variant, _
    Optional varTitleForDialog As Variant) As Variant
' Here's an example that gets an Access database name.
Dim strFilter As String
Dim lngFlags As Long
Dim varFileName As Variant
' Specify that the chosen file must already exist,
' don't change directories when you're done
' Also, don't bother displaying
' the read-only box. It'll only confuse people.
    lngFlags = ahtOFN_FILEMUSTEXIST Or _
                ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY Or ahtOFN_NOCHANGEDIR
    If IsMissing(varDirectory) Then
        varDirectory = ""
    End If
    If IsMissing(varTitleForDialog) Then
        varTitleForDialog = ""
    End If

    ' Define the filter string and allocate space in the "c"
    ' string Duplicate this line with changes as necessary for
    ' more file templates.
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, _
                "Access (*.mdb)", "*.MDB;*.MDA")
    ' Now actually call to get the file name.
    varFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                    OpenFile:=True, _
                    InitialDir:=varDirectory, _
                    Filter:=strFilter, _
                    Flags:=lngFlags, _
                    DialogTitle:=varTitleForDialog)
    If Not IsNull(varFileName) Then
        varFileName = TrimNull(varFileName)
    End If
    GetOpenFile = varFileName
End Function

Function ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
            Optional ByRef Flags As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal InitialDir As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal Filter As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal FilterIndex As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal DefaultExt As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal FileName As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal DialogTitle As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal hwnd As Variant, _
            Optional ByVal OpenFile As Variant) As Variant
' This is the entry point you'll use to call the common
' file open/save dialog. The parameters are listed
' below, and all are optional.
'
' In:
' Flags: one or more of the ahtOFN_* constants, OR'd together.
' InitialDir: the directory in which to first look
' Filter: a set of file filters, set up by calling
' AddFilterItem. See examples.
' FilterIndex: 1-based integer indicating which filter
' set to use, by default (1 if unspecified)
' DefaultExt: Extension to use if the user doesn't enter one.
' Only useful on file saves.
' FileName: Default value for the file name text box.
' DialogTitle: Title for the dialog.
' hWnd: parent window handle
' OpenFile: Boolean(True=Open File/False=Save As)
' Out:
' Return Value: Either Null or the selected filename
Dim OFN As tagOPENFILENAME
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileTitle As String
Dim fResult As Boolean
    ' Give the dialog a caption title.
    If IsMissing(InitialDir) Then InitialDir = CurDir
    If IsMissing(Filter) Then Filter = ""
    If IsMissing(FilterIndex) Then FilterIndex = 1
    If IsMissing(Flags) Then Flags = 0&
    If IsMissing(DefaultExt) Then DefaultExt = ""
    If IsMissing(FileName) Then FileName = ""
    If IsMissing(DialogTitle) Then DialogTitle = ""
    If IsMissing(hwnd) Then hwnd = Application.hWndAccessApp
    If IsMissing(OpenFile) Then OpenFile = True
    ' Allocate string space for the returned strings.
    strFileName = Left(FileName & String(256, 0), 256)
    strFileTitle = String(256, 0)
    ' Set up the data structure before you call the function
    With OFN
        .lStructSize = Len(OFN)
        .hwndOwner = hwnd
        .strFilter = Filter
        .nFilterIndex = FilterIndex
        .strFile = strFileName
        .nMaxFile = Len(strFileName)
        .strFileTitle = strFileTitle
        .nMaxFileTitle = Len(strFileTitle)
        .strTitle = DialogTitle
        .Flags = Flags
        .strDefExt = DefaultExt
        .strInitialDir = InitialDir
        ' Didn't think most people would want to deal with
        ' these options.
        .hInstance = 0
        '.strCustomFilter = ""
        '.nMaxCustFilter = 0
        .lpfnHook = 0
        'New for NT 4.0
        .strCustomFilter = String(255, 0)
        .nMaxCustFilter = 255
    End With
    ' This will pass the desired data structure to the
    ' Windows API, which will in turn it uses to display
    ' the Open/Save As Dialog.
    If OpenFile Then
        fResult = aht_apiGetOpenFileName(OFN)
    Else
        fResult = aht_apiGetSaveFileName(OFN)
    End If

    ' The function call filled in the strFileTitle member
    ' of the structure. You'll have to write special code
    ' to retrieve that if you're interested.
    If fResult Then
        ' You might care to check the Flags member of the
        ' structure to get information about the chosen file.
        ' In this example, if you bothered to pass in a
        ' value for Flags, we'll fill it in with the outgoing
        ' Flags value.
        If Not IsMissing(Flags) Then Flags = OFN.Flags
        ahtCommonFileOpenSave = TrimNull(OFN.strFile)
    Else
        ahtCommonFileOpenSave = vbNullString
    End If
End Function

Function ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter As String, _
    strDescription As String, Optional varItem As Variant) As String
' Tack a new chunk onto the file filter.
' That is, take the old value, stick onto it the description,
' (like "Databases"), a null character, the skeleton
' (like "*.mdb;*.mda") and a final null character.

    If IsMissing(varItem) Then varItem = "*.*"
    ahtAddFilterItem = strFilter & _
                strDescription & vbNullChar & _
                varItem & vbNullChar
End Function

Private Function TrimNull(ByVal strItem As String) As String
Dim intPos As Integer
    intPos = InStr(strItem, vbNullChar)
    If intPos > 0 Then
        TrimNull = Left(strItem, intPos - 1)
    Else
        TrimNull = strItem
    End If
End Function
'************** Code End *****************
```

Comment: [Application.FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196794.aspx) is an easy alternative.

Comment: I would re-think using Access 64 bit. There are very few reasons for using it and even Microsoft recommends 32 bit. Mainly that you are working with extremely large numbers. Here are a couple of links. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261?ui=en-US&rs=en-SG&ad=SG

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simple use a `FileDialog` to open up any dialog box you want as HansUp suggested.

```
' Allows you to open any type of file dialog
' 1 - open
' 2 - save as
' 3 - file picker
' 4 - folder picker
' Filters is a 2D array of filter options.  Example: ReDim filters(0, 0 To 1)
'                                                    filters(0, 0) = "All Files"  - Description
'                                                    filters(0, 1) = "*.*"        - Filter
' separate filter conditions with a ; to include multiple filters in one option like "*.xlsx; *.xls; *.xlsm" '
Function FileDialog(Dialog As Integer, _
                    Optional Multi As Boolean = False, _
                    Optional Title As String = "File Dialog", _
                    Optional filters As Variant) As Variant
    Dim Dlg As Object

    Set Dlg = Access.Application.FileDialog(Dialog)
    Dim i As Integer
    With Dlg
        .Title = Title
        If Dialog = 3 Then
            If Not IsMissing(filters) Then
                '.filters.Clear
                For i = LBound(filters, 1) To UBound(filters, 1)
                    .filters.Add filters(i, 0), filters(i, 1)
                Next
            Else
                .filters.Clear ' filters will be saved from last open
                .filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
            End If
        End If
        .AllowMultiSelect = Multi
        Dim varMulti As Variant
        i = 0
        Dim selectedFiles() As String
        ' if true user picked a file, if false user clicked cancel
        If .Show Then
            If .AllowMultiSelect And .selectedItems.count > 1 Then
                ReDim selectedFiles(0 To .selectedItems.count - 1)
                For Each varMulti In .selectedItems
                   selectedFiles(i) = .selectedItems(i + 1)
                   i = i + 1
                Next
                FileDialog = selectedFiles
            Else
                FileDialog = .selectedItems(1)
            End If
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With

    'FileDialog = Dlg.selecteditems(1)
End Function
```

Comment: As I understand it, Application.FileDialog was introduced for Office 2010 and we still have some PCs with Office 2007. Thanks for the code!

Comment: [Access 2007 Application.FileDialog Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213476(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If any other poor soul comes across this and needs an updated version of ahtCommonFileOpenSave that works with 32/64 bit, I updated it to check for VBA7 first:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Declare PtrSafe Function aht_apiGetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean
#Else
Declare Function aht_apiGetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Declare PtrSafe Function aht_apiGetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetSaveFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean
#Else
Declare Function aht_apiGetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    Alias "GetSaveFileNameA" (OFN As tagOPENFILENAME) As Boolean
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Declare PtrSafe Function CommDlgExtendedError Lib "comdlg32.dll" () As Long
#Else
Declare Function CommDlgExtendedError Lib "comdlg32.dll" () As Long
#End If


Function ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
        Optional ByRef Flags As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal InitialDir As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal Filter As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal FilterIndex As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal DefaultExt As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal FileName As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal DialogTitle As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal hwnd As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal OpenFile As Variant) As Variant

If IsMissing(InitialDir) Then InitialDir = CurDir
If IsMissing(Filter) Then Filter = ""
If IsMissing(FilterIndex) Then FilterIndex = 1
If IsMissing(OpenFile) Then OpenFile = True
If IsMissing(DialogTitle) Then DialogTitle = ""


#If VBA7 Then
    If OpenFile Then
        
        With Application.FileDialog(3) ' const msoFileDialogFilePicker = 3
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            
            ' deal with filters
            .Filters.Clear
            Dim FiltersArray() As String
            FiltersArray = Split(Filter, vbNullChar)
            For ct = 0 To UBound(FiltersArray) - 2 Step 2
                .Filters.Add FiltersArray(i), FiltersArray(i + 1)
            Next
            
            .FilterIndex = FilterIndex
            .Title = DialogTitle
            
            If .Show <> 0 Then
                ahtCommonFileOpenSave = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else
                ahtCommonFileOpenSave = vbNullString
            End If
        End With
    Else
        ' not sure how to do a save file in new VBA... 20181127 Jace Gregg
    End If
#Else
    ' This is the entry point you'll use to call the common
    ' file open/save dialog. The parameters are listed
    ' below, and all are optional.
    '
    ' In:
    ' Flags: one or more of the ahtOFN_* constants, OR'd together.
    ' InitialDir: the directory in which to first look
    ' Filter: a set of file filters, set up by calling
    ' AddFilterItem. See examples.
    ' FilterIndex: 1-based integer indicating which filter
    ' set to use, by default (1 if unspecified)
    ' DefaultExt: Extension to use if the user doesn't enter one.
    ' Only useful on file saves.
    ' FileName: Default value for the file name text box.
    ' DialogTitle: Title for the dialog.
    ' hWnd: parent window handle
    ' OpenFile: Boolean(True=Open File/False=Save As)
    ' Out:
    ' Return Value: Either Null or the selected filename
    Dim OFN As tagOPENFILENAME
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strFileTitle As String
    Dim fResult As Boolean
    
    ' Give the dialog a caption title.
    If IsMissing(Flags) Then Flags = 0&
    If IsMissing(DefaultExt) Then DefaultExt = ""
    If IsMissing(FileName) Then FileName = ""
    If IsMissing(hwnd) Then hwnd = Application.hWndAccessApp
    
    ' Allocate string space for the returned strings.
    strFilename = Left(FileName & String(256, 0), 256)
    strFileTitle = String(256, 0)
    ' Set up the data structure before you call the function
    With OFN
        .lStructSize = Len(OFN)
        .hwndOwner = hwnd
        .strFilter = Filter
        .nFilterIndex = FilterIndex
        .strFile = strFilename
        .nMaxFile = Len(strFilename)
        .strFileTitle = strFileTitle
        .nMaxFileTitle = Len(strFileTitle)
        .strTitle = DialogTitle
        .Flags = Flags
        .strDefExt = DefaultExt
        .strInitialDir = InitialDir
        ' Didn't think most people would want to deal with
        ' these options.
        .hInstance = 0
        '.strCustomFilter = ""
        '.nMaxCustFilter = 0
        .lpfnHook = 0
        'New for NT 4.0
        .strCustomFilter = String(255, 0)
        .nMaxCustFilter = 255
    End With
    ' This will pass the desired data structure to the
    ' Windows API, which will in turn it uses to display
    ' the Open/Save As Dialog.
    If OpenFile Then
        fResult = aht_apiGetOpenFileName(OFN)
    Else
        fResult = aht_apiGetSaveFileName(OFN)
    End If

    ' The function call filled in the strFileTitle member
    ' of the structure. You'll have to write special code
    ' to retrieve that if you're interested.
    If fResult Then
        ' You might care to check the Flags member of the
        ' structure to get information about the chosen file.
        ' In this example, if you bothered to pass in a
        ' value for Flags, we'll fill it in with the outgoing
        ' Flags value.
        If Not IsMissing(Flags) Then Flags = OFN.Flags
        ahtCommonFileOpenSave = TrimNull(OFN.strFile)
    Else
        ahtCommonFileOpenSave = vbNullString
    End If
#End If
```

End Function