Code for MS Access to click on image in form to set the filename for that image into table
I have an Access database that someone else set up for me many years ago.  It shows images of my cards in a form for each record.  When I add a new card I could click on the image in the continuous form and it would open up a dialog box for me to select the image.  When I selected the image it would save the path of that image to the data table so that every time I viewed the form for that record it then showed that image. Below is the code I have for this.  But it suddenly stopped working and always gives me the cancelled operation error. The file path is correct. Can anyone help with this?
Private Sub photoideaframe_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
' Purpose    : Use the API to open the Windows Common Dialog for the user to select a file
' Parameters : Cancel -- if set to true on Exit, cancels opening the form
' Created/Modified    : 6/24/99,
'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim lngFlags As Long
     Dim strPathAndFile As String
    Me.AllowDeletions = False
    strPathAndFile = ahtCommonFileOpenSave(InitialDir:="C:\Users\selin\OneDrive\cards\Ideas", _
        Filter:=strFilter, FilterIndex:=3, Flags:=lngFlags, _
        DialogTitle:="Choose an Image File")
        
    If Len(strPathAndFile) = 0 Then
        If (Eval("MsgBox ('    You Cancelled the Operation!@The previous picture will be kept RS.@@',10,' Add Image')")) = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "user clicked YES"
Else
End If
    Else
         Me![photoideaframe].Picture = strPathAndFile
         Me![photoidea] = strPathAndFile
         
    End If
              
    ' Since you passed in a variable for lngFlags,
    ' the function places the output flags value in the variable.
    
Exit_Sub:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.number & " : " & Err.Description & " in Form_Open", vbExclamation, "Images in Access Example"
    Resume Exit_Sub
End Sub


What debugging have you done? I see the error handler code is disabled so have you stepped through code? This is first time I've ever seen ahtCommonFileOpenSave code. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948215/convert-open-dialog-vba-code-to-64-bit

Since you don't show the API declarations, your posted code is not complete.

For reference, ahtCommonFileOpenSave is an old API wrapper by Getz/Litwin.

@Selina: please read Debugging VBA Code
